# Is there a C++ function to operate on rotation?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to give a camera in 3D space a tendency to try and settle behind the player's car in a racing game. Initially just using the yaw- the rotations of the camera and the car around y, as if, for the moment, the car is always on a flat plane. If I add 180 to the car's rotation, and the count begins again at zero if it passes 360, that would give me the rotation that the camera moves towards.

Obviously writing a function to return the correct value is trivial, but are there functions in libraries that already do this, or some faster solution? It strikes me as being quite an expensive way of going about it...

Comment: What do you mean "C++ function"? What libraries are you using? [Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/) has a lot of 3D manipulation functions, but you probably have equivalent functions in whatever engine you're using.

Comment: Usually graphic libraries comes with a well suited set of transform functions. Which toolkit are you using?

Comment: I'm using Polycode. I think it has Bullet Physics included..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking how to add numbers and "wrap around" so that you go back to 0 after 360, you can use the modulo operator `%`  for integers, and the [std::fmod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) function for floating point numbers.

Using radians is usually better than using degrees, though.